# Error 28 "Out of Stack Space" executing a huge query with VB6 & ADO 2.8

Tags: postgresql, vb6, oledb, ado, postgis

**Scenario:**
Executing an SQL command from a Visual Basic 6 application using ADO Connection.Execute method through PostgreSQL OLEDB Provider to a PostgreSQL 9.2 database.

**Query:**
It's a simple `EXECUTE prepared_statement_name (x, y, z)`, though it involves a PostGIS geometry type, thus it becomes something like:

```
EXECUTE prepared_statement_name (1, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))', 900001));
```

**Problem:**
When the geometry is a huge and complex MULTIPOLYGON which contains many vertexes, the query becomes very lengthy (a few thousands characters) and the `Connection.Execute` method causes a Error 28: "Out Of Stack Space".

There is no recursion or nested loops involved in the process, it's quite clear the error is due to the excessive length of the query.

I think I could avoid the error if I passed the huge query in "chunks" to the provider before executing it, but this is just an idea and I don't know wether it is possible or not and how.

I have no clue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There may not be recursion or loops in your code, but there may well be internal to Postgre/PostGIS. I expect your only option is to restructure yoru query or do it in chunks. If you can provide a sample of a query that overflows someone may be able to help further.

Comment: Um, VB6? From, what, 1998, end-of-life'd in 2005? With PostGIS? Seems like a weird combo. You seem to have forgotten to mention your PostgreSQL, PostGIS and psqlODBC versions.

Comment: @Deanna Thank you for the comment, but it is not related to recursion in any way. The same query executes fine in any other client (eg. pgAdminIII). The query is exactly the one in the question, just add a few thousands vertex to the polygon.

Comment: @Craig Ringer  Yes I'm aware VB6 is obsolete and it sounds like a "weird combo" (funny one), but this is what I got and I must fix it, legacy software is the worst software. PostgreSQL 9.2, PostGIS 2.0, pgFoundry PgOleDb 1.0.0.20 are the versions (yes, those latest releases makes the vb6 combo even worse...)

Comment: @Eggplant Fair enough ... I worked on some 1983 (!!) software for Microsoft Xenix/386 last year, so I know what the pain is like. Anyhow, first: if you execute a query that fails in VB6 via `psql` directly, does it fail with the same error? Or does it succeed when run directly via `psql`?

Comment: @CraigRinger I wrote it in the answer to Deanna: the query itself is fine, it executes is psql and pgAdminIII flawlessly. After all it's just an `EXECUTE` which performs a simple `INSERT` in a table with 3 fields. The query works fine in VB6 until the CommandString is not huge (about 100k characters is alright, haven't checked the exact size).

Comment: @Eggplant What's the point, the command string is changing, and (maybe indirectly) resulting in this problem. Seeing a sample will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like this is a VB6 level problem and you're already on current Pg versions I fear you may have to use some specacularly ugly workarounds.

If at all possible, try to find a way to increase the VB6 query buffer size, send the query in chunks via the VB6 ODBC interface, etc. Consider the following an absolute last resort.

Maybe this will give you some saner clues. I don't speak VB6 (thankfully) so I can't evaulate it: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/61340-error-28-out-stack-space.html

**Use the following only as a last resort if all else fails**:

- Create a `TEMPORARY` table like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_query(id integer, text querychunk)`.
- `INSERT INTO` the temporary table your statement, chunk by chunk, using parameterised queries to avoid quoting issues.
- Create a wrapper PL/PgSQL function that does a `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('EXECUTE stm_name(...)'`, passing the `string_agg` of the temp table as a parameter. Yes, that's amazingly ugly.

Here's a demo, some of the most horrible code I've ever written:

```
CREATE TABLE real_table (blah text);

PREPARE test_stm2(text) AS INSERT INTO real_table VALUES ($1);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data_chunks(datord integer, datchunk text);

PREPARE chunk_insert(integer, text) AS INSERT INTO data_chunks(datord,datchunk) VALUES ($1,$2);

-- You'll really want to do this via proper parameterised statements
-- to avoid quoting nightmares; I'm using dollar-quoting as a workaround
EXECUTE chunk_insert(0, $val$POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1,$val$);
EXECUTE chunk_insert(1, $val$ 1, 1 0, 0 0))$val$);

DO
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'EXECUTE test_stm2($1);'
        USING 
        (SELECT string_agg(datchunk,'' ORDER BY datord) FROM data_chunks);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM real_table ;
                 blah                  
---------------------------------------
 POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1, 1 0, 0 0))
(1 row)
```

A similar approach is possible for `SELECT`. You'd use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` within a function defined by `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` since `DO` blocks can't return a result. For example, for a query that returns a `SETOF INTEGER` you might write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_wrapper_func() RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('EXECUTE test_stm(%L);', (SELECT string_agg(datchunk,'' ORDER BY datord) FROM data_chunks));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You'll note the two-level `EXECUTE`. That's because the PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` is quite a different statement to SQL-level `EXECUTE`. PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` runs a string as dynamic SQL, wheras the SQL `EXECUTE` runs a prepared statement. Here we're running a prepared statement via dynamic SQL. Ick.

Wondering why I'm using PL/PgSQL? Because you can't use a subquery as an `EXECUTE` parameter. You can avoid the PL/PgSQL wrapper for the query if you don't run it as a prepared statement.

```
regress=> EXECUTE test_stm2( (SELECT string_agg(datchunk,'' ORDER BY datord) FROM data_chunks) );
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in EXECUTE parameter
```

Comment: Wow that's a ingenious solution, it may be "ugly", but it is also "safe": it keeps everything in some queries and I can still wrap all of that "ugly stuff" in a transaction! Meanwhile I was working on a uglier solution involving an additional layer in the application between the db class and ado, which was supposed to intercept all the commands and write a script file on the hard disk, and then execute it using psql (yes, launching psql from vb6...). Now THAT was ugly!!! :) I like your solution, it requires some queries to be changed but it avoids external interactions. Thank you very much!

Comment: I appreciate the effort and time you dedicated, really. I am able to implement the whole concept myself now, you saved me some major time loss! VB6 has scored again! :-)